# How to rotate an array of values within specific tag that contains a unique class by interval in jquery?

Tags: jquery, settimeout, innerhtml, setinterval

In the below piece of code I tried to make the objects with **class "rot"** to change the inner HTML by using the **value** attribute that includes an array of chars.

I want that this characters will rotate with an interval.

I noticed that the problem is in the inner **for** loop - I need there a **setTimeout** or something like this but it doesn't work.

any solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>


<span class="rot" value="$^%^@">currency</span>
<span class="rot" value="1^2^3">numbers</span>


<script>
function rotateItem()
{ 
 for(j=0;j<$(".rot").get().length;j++)
 {
  valueToRotate = $(".rot:eq("+j+")").attr("value").split("^"); 

  for(i=0;i<valueToRotate.length;i++)
  {
   $(".rot:eq("+j+")").html(valueToRotate[i]);
  }
 }
}
setInterval("rotateItem()",1000)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery .data() method to store the current index of each character being rotated. Also, the .each() method makes it very easy to perform some function for each element in a jQuery result.

Try this:

```
function rotateItem() {
    $('.rot').each(function() { // for each jquery object with class 'rot'
        var values = $(this).attr('value').split('^'); // get value array

        if ($(this).data('activeVal') == null) // if 'activeVal' is not set, set it to a default of 0
            $(this).data('activeVal', 0);
        else // otherwise increment through array indexes
            $(this).data('activeVal', ($(this).data('activeVal') + 1)%values.length); // mod (%) makes sure we loop back when we get to the end

        $(this).html(values[$(this).data('activeVal')]);
    });
}

setInterval(rotateItem,1000);
```